# How to convert pointer array to char array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have this:

```
typedef struct nodebase{
  char name[254];
  char sex;
  int  clientnum;
  int  cellphone;
  struct nodebase *next;
  struct nodebase *encoding;
} clientdata;
```

I have added `clientdata *curr[];` in seperate function. The reason why I made `*curr` into `*curr[]` instead is that this client data will be stored in a `.txt` file. So I came up with singly linked-list to read all the data and when the program `fscanf` every 5th variable, I will add 1 to `clientcounter`.

So, the `*curr[]` will be `*curr[clientcounter]`.

Now, I need to convert this pointer array into char array named `temp[clientcounter]` because char array is needed to evaluate something else later in the code.

I came up with this code below:(Using Tiny C on Windows)

```
void loaded_data_transfer(clientdata *curr,clientdata temp[],int clientcounter)
{
clientdata temp[] = {0};

temp[clientcounter].name = curr[clientcounter]->name;
temp[clientcounter].sex = curr[clientcounter]->sex;
temp[clientcounter].clientnum = curr[clientcounter]->clientnum;
temp[clientcounter].cellphone = curr[clientcounter]->cellphone;

}
```

The problem is, Tiny C is giving me an error: `lvalue expected` at `temp[clientcounter.name = ...` part. Can anyone tell me what did I do wrong?

And if anyone knows a better way to keep track of the `curr` of clientdata by using counter and by using singly linked-list, please let me know.

Comment: You say that `curr` is `clientdata *curr[]` in `main`, but the `curr` in your function is `clientdata *curr`, what's up with that?

Comment: @us2012  Sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: Why do you create second variable `clientdata temp[] = {0};` when you already have one `temp` on function parameter list?

Comment: @user694733 I thought `clientdata temp[] = {0};` would initialize the `temp` in function parameter list?

Comment: @BeginnerC: No. You're declaring and initialising a _new_ variable. You cannot initialise something that already exists. The parameter is initialised at the call site (ideally).

Comment: Why are you saying temp is char array when it's clearly clientdata array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you meant to copy the entire struct:

```
void loaded_data_transfer(clientdata * curr, clientdata temp[], int clientcounter)
{
    temp[clientcounter] = *curr; // Copy entire struct
}
```

It should work, because your struct doesn't any pointer members.

I am assuming you use it like this

```
clientdata * curr[CURR_SIZE];
clientdata temp[TEMP_SIZE];
/* init curr elements here */
loaded_data_transfer(*curr[clientcounter], temp, clientcounter);
```

Comment: You better include the function call as well in code. Then i can help with the precise fix

Comment: @BeginnerC I had i little misunderstaning what function parameters types you meant to use. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign an array to another. You should use strcpy or strncpy

```
strcpy(temp[clientcounter].name, curr[clientcounter]->name);
```

Comment: How about assigning `int`, instead of `char` ?

Comment: @BeginnerC Problem here is not `int` or `char`. It is that `name` is an **array**.

Comment: Oh i thought he meant using a single int instead of a char array. I guess i wrote clearly that you cannot copy arrays this way, irrespective of their types.

Comment: @user694733 I was just asking if there is a way to assign `int`

Comment: @BeginnerC What book or tutorial are you using to learn about C? It sounds like you should review the chapter about value assignments and array assignments/copying.

Comment: @RedX Actually, I am just a beginner, learning C in school. If you could suggest me a good book, I shall review & learn more.

Comment: @BeginnerC See [this list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 0):

Also, your declaration should be:

```
void loaded_data_transfer(clientdata *curr[],...
```